# How to update User model while getting existed info?

Tags: python, django

There is something wrong with my edit_profile code. I'm using "settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL". When I try to edit profile, it turned out that all the fill box was blank. I want the existing information to be there so the user would be editing their profile easier. Please help me.

accounts/models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
    address_number = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True,blank=True)
    road = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
    kwang = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
    ked = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
    postal = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    mobile = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

accounts/views.py

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    """Display User Profile"""
    user = request.user
    profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=user)
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', {
        'profile': profile
    })


@login_required
def edit_profile(request,id):
    user = request.user
    form = ProfileForm(instance=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(instance=user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Updated the Profile  Successfully!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))

    return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Comment: May be you should pass initial `form` values

Answer (score 0):

You have used `ProfileForm(instance=user, data=request.POST)`.Here  you have used instance of user that is wrong.

The instance should be of UserProfile object not user.

```
ProfileForm(instance=UserProfile.objects.get(user=user), data=request.POST)
```

It should solve the issue